# Powerautomate Flow: sharepoint list name suddenly changed

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-list

We have had some flows running now for a few years and all of a sudden in a Get Elements action, the list name of a sharepoint list is displayed as "a6f9e2d3-ba68-478a-b61b-520060a4aa46" and the flow now breaks as it cannot find a list with this name.

Why does this happen and how can i find out which list it was originally?

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following PowerShell command to get the name of the site.

```
#Config Parameters
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$ListGUID = [System.Guid]("a6f9e2d3-ba68-478a-b61b-520060a4aa46")
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get list by GUID
$List = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListGUID

#Get List Name
Write-host "List Name:" $List.Title
```

[image]

**Please perform the following troubleshooting:**

1.Please check if the list exists

2.If the list still exists, you can try to edit the "Site Address" and "List Name" in the flow. Then save and rerun the test.